# How to translate "Dream with me"?

Tags: traducción, preposiciones

The phrase *dream about/of* is translated as *Soñar con* in Spanish.

If I literally wanted someone to dream with me (and not dream about me), how would I say that? For example, a character in the movie Inception might ask another person to dream with them, and they mean "join me in a shared dream" and would definitely not be asking the other person to dream about them.

Would it be enough to just add the word junto: *sueña junto conmigo*?

I realize this is kind of a contrived question, so sorry.

Comment: The closest translation should be "*sueña conmigo*" ;)

Comment: @Flxtr but doesn't that translate to "dream about me" instead of "dream with me"?

Comment: Oh, I see your point. In the movie the person A is inviting the person B to share and be together in the same dream, I think "*sueña junto conmigo*" is good enough but the context matters ;)

Comment: The shortest I can think of is _soñemos juntos_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is indeed contrived, because the situation in question is only possible in fiction (so far) and therefore common language is not really prepared to express it. Prepositions are often arbitrary and it's just a coincidence that in Spanish the phrase goes *soñar con…*.

You can let context do its job and just use *Sueña conmigo.* Or you can say more explicitly *Sueña junto conmigo*, which sounds a bit off and has no poetry or sense of intimacy in it. Or maybe you could paraphrase a bit and say:

- *Acompáñame a soñar*, or maybe
- *Ven conmigo a soñar*.

The former has a good precedent (it sounds like a slogan or a song title, which it is, actually). The latter resolves the ambiguity of the meaning of *con* by placing the preposition next to a different verb.

Comment: Yeah, the Inception example is a little far-fetched, but your song title example made me realize the phrase has other uses. There are songs in English called _Dream with Me_ and I could imagine an alternate reality version of Martin Luther King Jr.'s speech where he uses that title instead of _I Have a Dream_. So thanks for the _Acompáñame a soñar_ example.

Answer (score 2):

My answer will be short.

The one that sounds more natural to me is

> Sueña conmigo

But it is right that it can also be understood as "dream about me", but the context would make the rest. If, anyways, you want to explicitly make the difference, what I'd say is

> Sueña junto a mí.

Which is the closest way that doesn't sound bad to me, and it means the same. What's more, I think I've heard it in some children movies. For me it definitely sounds much better than "sueña junto conmigo".

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine someone saying this without any fantasy/science fiction.  It's a romantic idea.  After all, *soñar | dream* isn't just about what we do when we're asleep.  Here's one way that occurs to me to express your idea:

> Ven a estar a mi lado en mi sueño. *Or* Acompáñame en mi sueño.

Now let's go a little farther with it.  Let's say that A says to their partner, "Last night I dreamed that I half woke up from a beautiful dream, and took your hand to take you back into my dream with me.  Let's try it tonight!  Let's see if it works!"

> Anoche soñé que me medio desperté de un sueño muy bello, y te agarré de la mano para llevarte conmigo a mi sueño otra vez.  Vamos a probarlo etc.

Although I don't agree with Pablo about the idea being too contrived to come up in natural conversation, I do agree that in the right context, "Sueña conmigo" could work.

*Note about my quasi-translation: I tend to take a gestalt approach to converting an idea from one language to the other.  I think about the idea behind the original sentence and then let it express itself in the other language.  So my results might be pretty different from what one would get from a strict* translation *as such.  So, I'm not sure whether my answer is quite what you were after....*